# Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`? Como lo corrijo?

Tags: html, nodejs, reactjs, jsx

Dentro de la consola de google me salta ese error y no me deja depositar unos valores dentro de un array
Es la primera vez que intento hacer una pagina web. Estaba siguiendo un video, soy muy principiante, les pido que me expliquen con detalle si pueden! gracias

[image: Error en la consola de google]

[image: Error en VS usando react]

Comment: Cambia el tag de class a className

Comment: pues en React la propiedad 'class' que podes encontrar en Html puro se llama 'className' en los componentes de React.

Comment: Hola @user318972, te recomiendo que agregues el código que tienes hecho, para evitar que te den votos negativos, y/o te cierren la pregunta, también puedes pasarte por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Comment: probablemente en algún lado tenes un array u objeto de atributos/propiedades que se mapea a un elemento DOM y al intentar rellenar o leer los valores no encuentra uno llamado `class` la sugerencia del warning es [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/className)